# having any options for circle click event on map and marker as visible false

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function setCircleMap(lat,lng,Diameter){ 
// lat,lng,diameter get values from Server   
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);   
                var mapOptions = {          
                    center:  myLatLng,          
                    zoom: 15,          
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                    },      
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
                    },
                    panControl: true,
                    panControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
                    }
                };        
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("circleMap-canvas"), mapOptions);
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
                });
                var circleOptions = {
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#FF0000",//32EBEB
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    map: map,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                    radius: parseInt(Diameter,10)
                };
                AOICircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
```

- from above code i got the circle on map,
- but now i tried click on circle i need to get circle latitude,longitude values,
- i tried with this code,

  ```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(AOICircle ,"click",function(e){
              alert("clicked")//not get any alert
              });
  ```
- is circle having event click option in v3-API,
- if give solution very helpfull for me.

Comment: are you getting any javascript error?  Where abouts in your code have you added this event listener?  The Circle class does have a click event, so it should be fine. What do you get if you do `console.log(AOICircle)` ?

Comment: You are missing the opening `{` on your `setCircleMap` function. Is this a typo?

Comment: @ MrUpsidown thanks for replay - i havein coding missing in this quation.

Comment: @ duncan - i did not get any errors i saw circle on map also.

Comment: Why rollback my edits? When someone edits your posts, there usually is a reason...

Comment: @ MrUpsidown -i am very sorry.in coding  **{** missed.so updating code..

Comment: Try to define a `var` for `AOICircle` - `var AOICircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [google.maps.event.addListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) (not addDomListener) on a google.maps.Circle.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(AOICircle ,"click",function(e){
        alert("clicked")
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc59V/)

Answer (score -1):

Circle is an object of the Google Map, so is is not clickable.  To make a circle clickable you have to use an image (bitmap or image), and then you can have your custom click events on that.

Comment: sorry anwer was not complete ... now have edited that u can check it .. sorry for inconvenience..

Comment: it's OK, I just wasn't sure that you noticed that half the answer was missing.

Comment: thanx for that dear.